# SKLearn: Dummy Variables for Label Encoded Categorical Values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I begin by setting my X from the excel dataset and converting it into matrix values:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
```

So I have two columns for X I need to label encode (countries and gender). There are three countries, Spain, France, and Germany, and there are only two genders. I label encode them:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1]) # the three countries
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
```

Okay, now I need create dummy variable for the three countries, since they don't exist in a hierarchical relationship with one value higher than other. However, the new code doesn't work:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]
```

This code does not work. I read that ColumnTransformer with Onehotencoding is used now to create dummy variables, but I am having difficulty figuring it out. I did import necessary packages. I tried this, but it still does not work:

```
columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
X = columnTransformer.fit_transform(X)
```

Can someone help? Thanks. I just want to hot encode the three countries in the beginning after they are label encoded.

Comment: Could you please post some samples of the dataframe that you are worrking on?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way you can get dummies is by using pandas get_dummies function. Here, you don't even need to Label encode your data.

```
df_country = pd.get_dummies(X[:, 1])
df_gender = pd.get_dummies(X[:, 2]
```

Now, you get two dataframes One hot encoded as per country and gender columns. You can now append it to the dataframe X and delete the original gender and country columns.
    X = pd.concat([X, df_country, df_gender], axis = 1)

Comment: If you use a separate test set, to avoid leaking information from the test set, you may want to fit the function to generate dummy variables on the training set only and then apply it on the test set. get_dummies will not allow you to do that, but ColumnTransformer will.